# How to extract digital signature from pdf using python?

Tags: python

I am using python 3.7 and i want to extract digital signature from an invoice(pdf) and then verify the digital signature . How do i go about it...Please help
I do not have any idea regarding this digital signature extraction and need to start from scratch.

Thank You

Comment: Have you found a way to extract signature metadata from a PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with what a **DSA** is and the difference between that and a **MAC** or **hash**. A *digital signature algorithm* provides integrity, authentication, and non-repudiation, whereas a *Message Authentication Code* provides integrity and authentication, and a *hash* only provides integrity. 

Since you are starting from scratch, I will include some informal definitions:
**Integrity** - integrity is ensured when you can definitely say there have been no modifications.
**Authentication** - Authentication is ensured when you can verify that the data came from the intended source. Ex. I can prove that Tom sent me the PDF.
**Non-repudiation** - Non-repudiation is ensured when a third-party can verify both the data's integrity and authentication given only the data and the relevant info (public key typically). Ex. John can verify that I sent you the pdf.

So depending on which type of algorithm you need, here are a few examples:

**Hash**

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.sha256(open('file.pdf', 'r').read().encode()).hexdigest())
```

**MAC** - HMAC, *keyed hash*

```
import hashlib, hmac
print(hmac.digest(b"key", b"message", digest=hashlib.sha256))
```

**DSA** - using the `cryptography` package
Taken from [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/#welcome-to-pyca-cryptography)

```
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
>>> private_key = dsa.generate_private_key(
...     key_size=1024,
...     backend=default_backend()
... )
>>> data = b"this is some data I'd like to sign"
>>> signature = private_key.sign(
...     data,
...     hashes.SHA256()
... )
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that the verification process is documented on linked page.

Comment: Is there a way to extract signature metadata such as contact, location, reason, etc.?

Comment: Interesting that this answer does not answer the original question. There is nothing about extracting signatures from pdf.